# Error: unchecked call to DefaultComboBoxModel(E[])

Tags: java, compiler-errors, jcombobox

When I build / run my applet, made from the NetBeans Applet Form I get 2 errors:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to DefaultComboBoxModel(E[]) as a member of the raw type DefaultComboBoxModel
        levelBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" }));
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class DefaultComboBoxModel
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to setModel(ComboBoxModel<E>) as a member of the raw type JComboBox
        levelBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" }));
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class JComboBox
2 warnings
```

If I click on the dropdown I get an exclamation mark next to it. Why is that?

Also, this is with the "-Xlint:unchecked" option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]
```

should be replaced by

```
new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[]
```

This warning can be ignored as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But that only takes care of on error, the other one still remains:
`
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to setModel(ComboBoxModel<E>) as a member of the raw type JComboBox
        levelBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" }));
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class JComboBox
1 warning
`

Comment: It seems you also need to use type argument for the JComboBox. So where you are creating levelBox you need to use its type as JComboBox<String>. You may want to read about generics in java tutorials.